# OnClicking an Anchor Tag ,The checkboxes should get checked

Tags: javascript, html

. . I like to execute a code, in which onclicking a anchor tag. . all the checkboxes should get checked. and also again clicking the anchor tag the checkboxes should get unchecked.

HTML

```
<a id="checkAll">Select All</a>

<input type="checkbox" name="item_check'.$item_id.'" value="'.$item_id.'">
<input type="checkbox" name="item_check'.$item_id.'" value="'.$item_id.'">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an anchor, so it doesnt have a `checked` property:

```
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

If the anchor is simply a "Check All", then set the property to `true`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yV6Lj/

Comment: thanks. . but onclicking it again the checkbox should get unchecked. .

Comment: @Zain -- Specify that in your question then! Also, the wording on the link may be confusing...I would also just use a checkbox for this and then compare the value of the check all checkbox to see what to set the rest of the boxes to

Comment: I already have a checkbox, when checking it all checkboxes are getting checked and unchecked. but i need the same function to be done but with an anchor tag.

Comment: You'll have to set a flag then for when they're all checked and unchecked, and set the property based on that flag

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a button instead

**Anchor**

```
<a id="checkAll" href="#">Select All</a>

<input type="checkbox" name="item_check'.$item_id.'" value="'.$item_id.'">
<input type="checkbox" name="item_check'.$item_id.'" value="'.$item_id.'">


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

**Button**

```
<button id="buttonCheckAll">Check All</button>
<input type="checkbox" name="item_check'.$item_id.'" value="'.$item_id.'">
<input type="checkbox" name="item_check'.$item_id.'" value="'.$item_id.'">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```